# Different way of applying a transition and transform?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am applying transforms on hover on the first child and other children of my collection of box divs separately. But this is causing an issue when I hover out of the first child because the transition property for transforms on both the first child and other children is still the same, but the transforms are different. Hence I am looking for some other way to apply transition on the first child.

Issue on hoverout on first item on each grid - https://netflix-clone-by-shivam.herokuapp.com/

I tried using not(:first-child) on the transition property which resolves the issue but now it has no transition. I also tried adding the transition property with javascript but it brings the back the issue with transition.

```
//react - mapping over collectionItems is returning divs with class box

 <div className="preview">  

  {     
        movies
        ? (movieData.map(({id, ...otherProps}) => <CollectionItem key={id} {...otherProps} />))
        : null
  }
  {
        tvshow
        ? (tvData.map(({id, ...otherProps}) => <CollectionItem key={id} {...otherProps} />))
        : null
  }

</div>

//css

.preview {
display: flex;

cursor: pointer;

&:hover {
  .box {
    transform: translateX(-25%); //moves items on the left by 25%
  }
}

.box:hover ~ .box {
  transform: translateX(25%); //moves items on the right by 25%
}

.box:first-child:hover ~ .box {
 transform: translateX(50%); //moves items to the right of firstchild by 50%
}

.box {
  &:not(:first-child) {
  transition: transform 300ms ease 100ms;
}

  &:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  &:hover:first-child {
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to handle it separately. You simply need to set your `transform-origin: left;` on `:first-child` only (no hover). By placing it in `:hover` it is only is applied on hover vs on hover and hover out. Try replacing your current `.box` block at the end of your code with this:

```
.box {
    transition: transform 300ms ease 100ms;
    &:first-child { /* should only be &:fist-child */
      transform-origin: left;
    }
    &:hover {
      transform: scale(1.5);
    }
}
```